# Stackoverflow in InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, windows, stack-overflow

I have lots of controls (at least hundreds) added to my form, and quite a few of them are custom controls, and the code inside InitializeComponent is huge. Still, I simply cannot see how can there be any recursion and why does the stack overflow happen.
It only happens if I run the Debug version from inside VS (2008, it uses .net framework 3.5 and Winforms). If I just double click on the executable, the application runs.
Can someone tell me how is that possible, and what can I do to find out why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the code of your `InitializeComponent` method contains a lot of local variable / big local variables (e.g `struct` with a lot of fields) - that use almost all the stack space available, and when running under the debugger within VS there is a little bit less space in the stack, hence the error.

If this is the problem, it might be fixed converting local variables to class fields, and/or splitting the `InitInstance` method in various methods with their own local variables - that will share the same stack space.

Comment: This sounds logical. But if this is the case, what can I do? There is nothing there but the initialization of the controls of the user interface. I admit, there are lots of controls because this is a big application (the Form.Designer.cs file is over 2MB), but how can there be a limitation?

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is definitely worth a try. I use - apart from hundreds of 'stock' components like textboxes, listboxes, labels, checkboxes and radio buttons - also hundreds of instances of a custom numericupdown control, combobox, groupbox and a tab control. These custom controls use several local variables which are initialized when they are created in InitializeComponent. None of these controls were created by me, but I have their source code so I can try to modify them.

Comment: The type of the local variables can be integer, float, Color, etc. There are not so many of them per control, but since the number of controls is really big, maybe they can cause this.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing which might be relevant: this happens only when I compile to 64-bit. The application is native 64-bit and for a good reason, but I used to compile it separately as x86 code. This 32-bit version never had a problem like this and 'went through' initializecomponent almost instantly, but the 64-bit version, even when it does not stop with stackoverflow spends almost 20 seconds before it starts to execute the initializecomponent method.

Comment: Reference local variables uses twice the stack space in 64 bit than in 32 bit - so it would make sense that the stack overflow problem goes away in 32 bit. On the other hand the 20 second delay does not make much sense - maybe there is something else going on, difficult to say without having a look at the code.

Comment: I think you are definitely on the right track. I found this in the constructor of the custom numericupdown control:
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
this.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
Can this cause a problem, keeping in mind that I use literally hundreds of these controls?
Is there a way that I can show you the code? The strange thing is 20 second (or more) is needed before it even starts to execute what is inside InitializeComponent which is the first line of the form constructor.

Comment: Local variables inside the constructors should not be a problem - because they use space in the stack only while that constructor runs. The problem could/should be caused by local variables in the `InitializeComponent` itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25542/discussion-between-aronsatie-and-mimo)

Comment: Once again, thanks for your help. It looks like the custom combobox I have been using is most likely to blame. It has quite a few local variables/properties, and in the OnPaint event and in a few cases, it reads the properties defined for local variables (type: Color) rather than the local variables themselves. I guess that this is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

your best bet is to find out exactly where the exception is happening - control Alt E brings up the Exceptions dialog - click under Thrown for common language runtime exceptions and debugging will stop as soon as your error is thrown - from there you can view the call stack and trace the calls to see where you went wrong.  (If the shortcut doesn't work, you can click debug/exceptions in visual studio for the same thing)

(Just to be clear - the Exceptions window brings up a dialog with a list down the left, C++ exceptions, Common Language Runtime Exceptions, etc... you want to click the first checkbox in line with the Common Language Runtime Exceptions so that your code breaks as soon as you hit your issue  Then for further investiagtion, debug/windows/callstack - or control/alt C - which will quickly let you see if you do have recursion or some other issue.)

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it still just stops with the stackoverflow error message at a completely innocent line in InitializeComponent:

Comment: (lame response - but often apt) - if you restart visual studio?

Comment: I tried that, too, and sometimes it helps, the application starts once or twice, but sooner rather than later I get the unhandled stackoverflow exception message. I don't understand why the application can be run from outside VS without getting this message.

Comment: interestingly, there was  a fix for a similar issue for VS 2010 when lots of controls were on a web page...I wonder if it's visual studio weirdness.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2201993

Comment: The call stack does not tell me more unfortunately. Execution stops at this line (if it stops at all, because I have 30-40% chance that the application starts):
this.checkBox12.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;